# How to create a directory or set path to download folder in android 10 and above?

Tags: android

I have a app which have it's own downloader

Upto android 9 I'm using below code to set path to specific directory

```
File  file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Custom folder");
 if (!file.exists()) 
 {
 boolean f = file.mkdir();
 }
```

But with storage policy change this code doesn't work properly.

I tried

```
All files access permission
```

But App got rejected by Google and They suggested me to use Media store API , I read  Media store API documentation but I didn't find the way to set path to download folder.

So any solution to create a distinguish directory or at least a way to set path to android Download folder?

Comment: Change `"/Custom folder"` to "/Download".